# GitHub actions require to pass before merging conditionally

Tags: github-actions

I have a `front` workflow in GitHub Actions:

```
name: front
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - packages/front/**
jobs:
  install:
    ...
  lint:
    ...
  test:
    ...
```

I need the following:
If there are changes in `packages/front` enable merge if the workflow passes. If there are changes in another path allow to merge